# Implicit function theorem Question

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

Having a test soon and was looking at this Question without having any sure ideas on what to do. Thanks for your help.

1. Proove that near  $(x,y) = (1,1) $

Exist 2 Differential functions :

$ u(x,y)$ 
and $v(x,y) $

that also agree with

$$x=u^2-v^2 \\ y = 2uv $$
2.
(This is the tuff one) Proove that $u(x,y) \  v(x,y)$ agree with

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0
\\v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$$
Near $(x,y) = (1,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just quadratic equations. In fact, it is asking about the complex square root function.

Take the square of the second equation and remove $v$ with the help of the first equation. Then test the 4 solutions of the resulting biquadratic on the original equations.

Of course, you can also do what is demanded of you and compute the Jacobi matrix $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$ at $(u,v)=(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a branch of the square root, i.e.,
$$
u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=\sqrt{x+iy}.
$$
Or note that
$$
x^2+y^2=\cdots= (u^2+v^2)^2
$$
and thus $u^2+v^2=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$. Hence 
$$
u^2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}, \quad v^2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}.
$$
Choosing for example
$$
u(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}}, \quad v(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}},
$$
works!